# save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' Error while using Django Signal Dispatcher

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

**models.py**

```
class es_event(models.Model):
    #some attributes
    reg_applicants = models.FilePathField(path=None)
    ev_admin =  models.ForeignKey('es_user',related_name='events',on_delete=None)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.ev_name)
        return super(es_event, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('event_detail', kwargs={'id': self.id, 'slug': self.slug })
```

**views.py**

```
class CreateEventView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    login_url = "/login/"
    model = es_event
    fields = ['ev_name','ev_venue','ev_description','ev_date','registrant_name','registrant_age','registrant_phone','registrant_email','registrant_institution']
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.ev_admin = self.request.user.es_user
        return super(CreateEventView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Now when a new row is added to es_event. I want to set the **reg_applicants** field with a path(including filename)

eg: if **es_event.id** is 5 then filename should be **Registered_5.csv**

To do that I created this Signal in **models.py**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=es_event)
def set_csv_path(sender, **kwargs):
    rel_path = "reg_csv/Registered_{}.csv".format(sender.id)
    path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,rel_path)
    sender.reg_applicants = path
    sender.save()# error statement
```

which gives me this error

```
save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I think there is something wrong with the signal dispatcher function **set_csv_path()**. I don't know what it is

Answer (score 3):

You're using the wrong parameter. `sender` is the class to which the signal is connected. You need to also accept the instance parameter .

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=es_event)
def set_csv_path(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    rel_path = "reg_csv/Registered_{}.csv".format(instance.id)
    path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,rel_path)
    instance.reg_applicants = path
    instance.save()
```

Comment: I've tried it but I'm getting this error

__maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object__

Comment: Well, now think about what you are doing inside the handler: you're calling save. Which will invoke the post-save handler, which calls save... Really this should be in a *pre*-save handler, and you should not call save inside it.

Comment: I think there is some problem with this line in my CreateEventView

           __return super(es_event, self).save(*args, **kwargs)__

Comment: As I said, you should not call save inside the handler.

Comment: If I use pre_save, then the instance.id will be None, the id of the instance will be available only after saving it

Answer (score 0):

I also had the similar problem, turns out that the arguments of the receiver method cannot be renamed, you have to keep the **original name** as it is.
in my case my receiver was something like this,
`def my_receiver(sender, my_instance, created, **kwargs)`.
I had to change to `(sender, instance, created, **kwargs)`